# .htaccess for specific folder script only

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok,
I have a small problem with `.htaccess` RewriteRule.

I made simple website locally that uses RewriteRule for urls like:

```
http://localhost/ <- main page
http://localhost/log/ <- log page
etc.
```

I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /script
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

AuthUserFile c:\data\mysite\.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Secret place"
require valid-user
```

Since the site is ready and it's basically just a helpful script, I move the contents to `http://mysite/script/`

It all works when I open `http://mysite/script/`, but when I click on an url, it opens `http://mysite/script/log/` in browser bar, but loads `http://mysite/` front page content.

Meaning, the redirect doesn't let me read the necessaro `log` content but thinks it's a rewrite to the front page ( since the main site doesn't have a value `script/log/`.

Now, how can I set it to load the **real** `mysite/script/log` content?

Thanks in advance.

*EDIT:*

This is the `.htaccess` file on main site root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:range} !(^bytes=[^,]+(,[^,]+){0,4}$|^$)
RewriteRule .* - [F]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} (\&ch_lang\=[]{2}|)
RewriteRule  ^one-of-links$ ?main_page_extend=4011%1 [L]

php_value memory_limit 512M
```

Comment: Added additional info to original question.

Comment: Does the `log` directory exist? Are you sure there isn't an htaccess file in the log directory that's redirecting you?

Comment: @JonLin Nope. There are no other directories ( except for js, images etc ) that could cause that problem.

Comment: I tried recreating your scenario, and http://mysite/script/log/ gives 403 if /script/log/ folder exists, homepage if it doesn't... I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish here, since if you want http://mysite/script/log/ to display the index of /script/log you wouldn't need a rewrite (and the one shown wouldn't do anything if it existed per -d) and you don't want it to point at /index.php... what is http://mysite/script/log/ supposed to point to exactly if not /index.php or /script/log/index.php?

Comment: @WebChemist I fixed the problem. I needed `script/log/` to point to `script/index.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the `RewriteBase` to `/script`. Otherwise when the rewrite to `/index.php` happens, it goes to the document root's index.php (your front page), instead of the one in script.

Comment: All right, I got it working. I needed to change not only `RewriteBase /script` but also `RewriteRule . /script/index.php [L]`. You kinda showed me to the right direction.

Comment: @DainisAbols Ah, I didn't notice the leading slash in front of `index.php`. You could probably also just get rid of that slash.